# Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) - Forget Layer, and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to RNN, and I'm trying to figure out the specifics of LSTM cells and they're relation to TensorFlow: [Colah GitHub](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)
[image]
Does the GitHub website's example uses the same LSTM cell compared to TensorFlow? The only thing I got on the TensorFlow site was that basic LSTM cells uses the following architecture: [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2329.pdf) If it's the same architecture then I can hand compute the numbers for a LSTM cell and see if it matches.

Also when we set a basic LSTM cell in tensorflow, it takes in a `num_units` according to: [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cells_for_use_with_tensorflow_s_core_rnn_methods#BasicRNNCell)

```
tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell.__init__(num_units, input_size=None, activation=tanh)
```

Is this number of hidden state (h_t)) and cell state (C_t)?

According to the GitHub website, there isn't any mention the number of cell state and hidden states. I'm assuming they have to be the same number?

Comment: I'm sorry but deep learning is not something that you can follow a tutorial and you become a guru. That's my experience right now, months studying really hard to understand because they are complex. So if you're really new and want to understand how they work I recommend you Udemy courses from instructors: Lazy Programmer, and  SuperDataScience. If you are only interested in easy code you can try with Keras, it's a high level framework working on top of Tensorflow or Theano.

Comment: Is your question about GRU or LSTM? A GRU cell has a single state that is the same size of the output, whereas an LSTM cell has a two part state with components of equal size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementation looks the same as `GRUCell` class [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b723590631432584d0761c03285eabb55116c6d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L263) also points the same paper (specifically for gated) with [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1078v3.pdf) given in Colah's article. Parameter `num_units` is the number of cells (assuming that is the hidden layer) corresponds to `output_size` due property [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b723590631432584d0761c03285eabb55116c6d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L282).

Comment: What do you mean by gated? I'm new to RNNs. If it's long to explain, can you provide me a link that explains gated? Thanks

Comment: Hello, you have given example for GRUCell which means `gated recurrent`. Colah's article mentions cell & hidden state for the first time while explaining the GRU term.

Comment: Alright, I think I have yet to understand what GRU is. I shall find out later, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have found a better description [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-network-tutorial-part-4-implementing-a-grulstm-rnn-with-python-and-theano/). Though article relies on early version of the same paper, it is more explicit and mention things like output being the hidden state.